# How to clear cache in trueclient protocol loadrunner

Tags: javascript, java

I am working in loadrunner using Trueclient protocol, but when I am executing script for multiple iterations, the script is failing because of cache memory in the application. We need to clear the cache in each iteration.

Comment: Please refer to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312326/how-to-clear-cookies-in-loadrunner-12-50/37482038#37482038

Answer (score 0):

the following functions can be inserted as values in Ajax TruClient step elements.

Utils.clearCache()
Utils.clearCookies()

as you can figure out the first one clears the cache, the second one the cookies.